# What will be the Time Complexity of following code in terms of ‘n’?

Tags: java, time

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       for(int j = 1 ; j < k; j++){
         System.out.println(i + j);
       }
}
```

Shouldn't it be O(n^2).. But it is O(n)

Comment: You have one loop that depends on `n` in a linear fashion.  Why should the overall code be O(n^2)?  You could argue that it would be more useful to say it is O(n * k), but in terms of `n` it's just O(n).

Comment: @WJS hopefully not k=n haha

Comment: If k is always constant then it is O(n) otherwise it is O(n*k)